# Solving the Logarithmic equation $\log_x (3-2\sqrt2)=2$

Tags: logarithms

$$\log_x (3-2\sqrt2)=2$$ I can't solve it, I tried everything but I can't find the solution I tried logarithmic properties but nothing works, please help!

Comment: TeX: prefix the `log` with a backslash to make it upright: `\log` $\log$ vs. `log` $log$.

Comment: How about taking the square root of 3-2(surd2) that is if the equation is transformed from logarithmic to exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may banned after this comment, but technic might be helpful.

If you have had: 
$$ 3 + 2 \cdot \sqrt{2} $$
You would be see:
$$ (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2 $$
And carefully do calculations you may provide that this statements are the same.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply re-write with logarithm rules: $$x^2=3-2\sqrt2$$
because $$\log_ba=c \Leftrightarrow b^c=a$$

And the answer is as simple as taking the root.